# how to use Redux instead for useSate or how to store data using Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

```
const[datas,setdatas]=useState("")
```

i have been using useState for storing variable and while finishing the last task my higher official told me to use Redux to store change and perform action . i read it in blog youtube videos but I can't quite get to know the necessary about redux. can someone suggest me a easy example or solution for me?

Thanking you in advance.

Comment: Have you worked with React's context provider/consumer? I'd research that as a first step. Then you can watch something like https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pR4A9YONzuo Your boss/coworker would like you to use a global state management solution apparently. It solves the problem of accessing data that is needed by many react components throughout your app (like the name of the logged in user for example). React offers context as a simple solution, and libraries like redux are built on top of that.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a bunch of nested components in you app, you have to send props every time to the new nested component.
Then you feel like you want your states to be managed globally.
Otherwise you probably have to type same props again and again.

This is why Redux and other state managing modules are needed.
They put your state in a global storage and you can get that state in other component with props drilling. You only need to access global storage to get necessary state.

If your app has few components, redux or other state managing modules won't be necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Redux provides a easy way to pass data through the component tree without having to pass props down manually at every level, and you should only use it for global states.

I think you can keep using useState for local states.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I would like to answer in 3 points

**1. Understanding Redux**
I found this (three principles) to be the most helpful way to begin understanding Redux.
https://redux.js.org/understanding/thinking-in-redux/three-principles

**2. Why you have been asked to use redux?**
Considering your senior has asked you to use Redux, I am assuming you are only coding a part of a larger app (already using redux) and the state in question needs to be a "global state" for use by multiple other components. If that's not the case please look at other solutions like react's context provider or simply using local state and passing it down with props where needed.

**3. What else do you need to know?**
If point 2 holds, I would urge you to check with your senior/team for the existing implementation of redux store, reducers, middleWare and devTools.

Note : I found redux to be a complex tool and could understand and appreciate it only after using it for a while.